# Response from asynchronous server to asynchronous client is NULL in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, client, server

I have asynchronous communication between client and server. When the client receives a response from the server (ReceiveCallback), the response is stored in public static string response in my NetworkHandler class. I am trying to use this field in my GameHandler class, but it says that response is empty.
I am sure that my buffer in NetworkHandler is not empty, because I checked it.

*I think it happens because NetworkHandler.response is called before the response gets a value, but I am not sure and I don't know how to solve it...*

**See the comments in the code for more explanation...**

Please take a look at this image to see the null value in GameHandler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgyjJ.png And here to see the correct value in NetworkHandler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DXuO.png

```
class NetworkHandler
{
    public static string response = String.Empty;

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {         
        Socket remote = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received = remote.EndReceive(AR);

        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[received];            
        Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuffer, received);
        string serverData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuffer);
        response = serverData;
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket remote = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int sent = remote.EndSend(AR);
        remote.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _size, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), remote);
    }

    public static void sendData(string data)
    {
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        _client.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _client);
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        _client = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            _client.EndConnect(AR);
            _client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _size, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _client);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}

class GameHandler
{
    public void StartGame()
    {
        // SEND DATA USING BEGINSEND()
        SendData("<sg>");

        // THIS VALUE IS NULL!!! :(
        _response = NetworkHandler.response;

        // SO CODE INSIDE IF IS NOT EXECUTED :(
        if (_response != null)
        {
            // If you are the drawer.
            if (_response.Substring(0, 5) == "<dra>")
            etc.........
         }
     }

     public void SendData(string data)
     {
        NetworkHandler.sendData(data);
     }
}
```

Comment: Your example is missing a lot of code. So there's no way to offer a precise explanation. From the code you posted, it's not possible for the `NetworkHandler.response` field to ever be null; you initialize it to a non-null value, and you don't show any other assignment statement except one that can never return a null value. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on how to post a good question.

Comment: Are you sure your call to `_response = NetworkHandler.response;` happens **after** your response handler was called? Since your SendData is asynchronous, maybe your response was not yet received while execution of `StartGame` continued?

Comment: I will add more code in 1 minute. I thought this was all code needed, but apparently its not..

Comment: Extra code added and more pictures added...